# In R Shiny, format numbers in a table, but keep numeric instead of character

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display a table of values and format each value to include the tenths digit, even if it is zero. For example, 23 should display as 23.0. I know that I can do this by making each value a character using `formatC()`. The problem is that when I sort the column of characters, it would put 9.1 as the highest value in the example below even though it is actually the lowest, since it is sorting alphabetically instead of numerically.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12, dataTableOutput("test"))
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  output$test <- renderDataTable({
    data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 3), values = c("9.1", "23.0", "14.8"))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to force a specific format on values and still keep the values as numeric, or find a way to sort it numerically?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `DT::formatRound` with `digits=1`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12, dataTableOutput("test"))
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  output$test <- renderDataTable({
    data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 3), values = c("9.1", "23.0", "14.8")) |> 
      transform(values = as.numeric(values)) |> 
      datatable() |> 
      formatRound(2, digits = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6937
```

[image]